# performSegue being called but not actually segueing to VC2? (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, target-action

Can anyone spot my error?  The left bar button works to dismiss, however the action button calls `performSegue` but the UI doesn't change the VC?  Calling `showLinkPreviewController` inside `ViewDidLoad` works, so apparently it's a problem with the target/action?  A bug?

```
     let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissTimeline))
            timelineViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button

            let previewButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(showLinkPreviewViewController))
            timelineViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = previewButton

            // Create a navigation controller to hold the
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: timelineViewController)
            showDetailViewController(navigationController, sender: self)
        }
        func dismissTimeline() {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func showLinkPreviewViewController() {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLinkPreviewViewController", sender: self)
        }

  // Create a navigation controller to hold the
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: timelineViewController)
        showDetailViewController(navigationController, sender: self)
```

Comment: What's this `timelineViewController `, this is the issue, you didn't call the action on `self` but another view controller i think

Comment: It's a preloaded TableView of Tweets in the Fabric SDK, see the bottom of my code (updated).  I don't think that's the problem though, since I want my target to be my self (rootViewController)

Comment: Do you have custom segue code? If not, there is a simpler way to programmatically change views,

Comment: And if you do, can you include it because that is the last step before the view should change

Comment: I don't have a custom segue, just wired one up in the storyboard from VC1 to VC2

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a segue instead of a push?

Comment: Yes because I'm using prepareForSegue to pass information to the destination VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the segue was being performed but since I wasn't dismissing my current VC off the stack I couldn't see it:

The fix:

```
  func showLinkPreviewViewController() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLinkPreviewViewController", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use dispatch like this -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdScreen"] animated:YES];
});
```

or another way -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   func showLinkPreviewViewController() {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLinkPreviewViewController", sender: self)
        }
```

});

Comment: Thanks but it's not the async, tried that.  `dismissTimeline` works with the same exact code, and `showLinkPreviewController` works in VDL, which is why I can't figure out what the difference is.